# Moving question to Software Recomendation

Tags: discussion, migration, scope, software-recs-se

In the question [Yii Facebook Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953956/yii-facebook-button) the user is asking for extensions/plugins that can be used to implement a Facebook Like button. First of all, is this question off-topic? If so, when I try `flag -> off-topic -> belongs on another site`, there is no Software Recommendation option. Is it possible to move it there?

**UPDATE**

According to [What is required for a question to contain enough information](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) (thanks @Mat) this question is NOT a good fit for SR either.

Comment: Does that question meet the requirements of SR? (http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) - If you don't know, you should **not** be requesting a migration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the future, there might be. We don't establish migration paths to beta sites because we want to be *positively certain* that they'll be permanent fixtures on the network before we begin sending things to them.

There are also questions that would conceivably be much better suited for Code Review, but there won't be a path there until CR graduates, and then, only after we see how well migrations that mods have initiated fared.

Moderators can, at their discretion, migrate any question that is less than 60 days old to any site in the network. The best thing to do for now is to flag it, indicate that you think it belongs on Software Recommendations, and let them make the call.

That *particular* question would not be a good fit. Software Recommendations SE has some [very strict](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules) guidelines when it comes to what makes a good question there, that's why the quality is so high.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is off-topic. The OP is basically asking for some plugin recommendations. This line in the question gives that idea:

> I've looked at different available extensions but none of them seems to be maintained or updated anymore and I would like to use something that's not abandoned by its creators.

It is off-topic and would fit the following close-reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a **tool**, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

As for why you can't vote to migrate the question to Software Recommendations, that's because that site is still in its beta. Not all sites are listed as migration targets — mostly because people migrate stuff that's not really on-topic on the target site. If you think a question is on-topic on another site, flag it for moderator attention and use the "Other" flag to describe the issue. If the moderator agrees, they *may* migrate it.